# other Wesites addresses did not match as url

Tags: java, javascript, android

Hi i am using this code to match to the editbox text(where user input web addresses)

```
(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(txt_Editbox).matches())
```

but when the user input this url:

```
http://website.info?ques==two&t=p
```

it did'nt accept as url, it read as a text. could anyone help me to solve this or suggest to do anything else. ??
thank you.

Comment: is that == in ques==two there on purpose, it isn't supposed to be quest=two?

Comment: but this one exist. how would i validate this one?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is incorrect. It's missing a URL path separator `/`. Try matching with:

```
http://website.info/?ques=two&t=p
```

Comment: but this is the user wants to input. is there any way to validate this kind of url sr.?

Comment: This is incorrect. You must have a browser open and you can verify that none of the sites you're on can be reached if you remove the root `/` from their URL. That's just how valid URLs work. A `/` is required unless you want to open the homepage i.e. no URL path and no query string.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolve this problem instead of using

```
(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(txt_Editbox).matches())
```

i used

```
String urlname = "^(https?|ftp|file)://.+$";
Matcher matcherObj = Pattern.compile(urlname).matcher(txt_Editbox);
```

this one can accept all kinds of web addresses as long as this address exist, and now i am able to view this site: http://website.info?ques==two&t=p to my webview.